# Enconding problems with MySQL Database (web2project)

Tags: php, mysql, database, character-encoding

When I want to add the name of the project in Russian, the application saves the filled data in non-readable format into mysql database like`Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾ÐµÐºÑ‚ Ð½Ð¾Ð¼ÐµÑ€ Ñ‚Ñ€Ð¸ Ð´Ðµ Ñ„ÑˆÐ¾Ñ‹ÑÑˆÑ„Ñ‹Ð²Ð¾ ÑˆÑ‰Ñ„Ñ‹Ð¾Ð²ÑÑˆÑ‰Ñ‹Ð² (проект номер три де фшоысшфыво шщфыовсшщыв`) . But when i want to see the details about the current project, the view form of the project shows the data as its typed (e.g. `проект номер три де фшоысшфыво шщфыовсшщыв`).

Since the database is filled with non-utf8 format, the print view of project has the same inconveniences.

What should i change or delete so the inserting process of the data will be in proper way ?

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

Comment: I didn't get where data is not readable? in the database (viewed by a proper client like phpmyadmin) or when fetched using some php-mysql driver?

Comment: in the mysql database itself. please, look at the project_name and projec_short_name columns.

Btw, charset is utf8 as default format in config file

Comment: try connecting using this url `localhost/unicode?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8` if you are in localhost, then reinsert and check.

Answer (score 0):

`Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾ÐµÐºÑ` is Mojibake for `проек`.

This is the classic case of

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8 (good).
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- The column in the tables may or may not have been `CHARACTER SET utf8`, but it should have been that.

If you need to **fix for the data** it takes a "2-step ALTER", something like

```
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(...) ...;
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(...) ... CHARACTER SET utf8 ...;
```

where the lengths are big enough and the other "..." have whatever else (`NOT NULL`, etc) was already on the column.